# unable to retrive parent page information

Tags: wp-query, query

I am trying to display the parent page title, parent page id, current title and current id on a page via a plugin.

I have the below code which I then echo the value of each. The trouble I am having is that on a parent page and a sub page the `$parentTitle` and `$parentID` are returning the current title and ID.

I don't see anything wrong with the below.

```
$parentTitle = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
$parentID = get_the_ID($post->post_parent);
$currentTitle = get_the_title($post);
$currentID = get_the_ID();
```

To display these values I am simply doing:

```
echo $parentTitle;
echo $parentID;
echo $currentTitle;
echo $currentID;
```

I am this within a function in my plugin and the output in `wp_footer`

have I missed something?

Comment: Do you call `global $post` in your function before trying to access its values?

Comment: Sorry, yes I have got that too. I have tried with and without with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

As defined by the WordPress codex use this to get the parent `get_post_ancestors( $post )` , The direct parent is returned as the first value in the array.

Edit: `get_post_ancestors( get_queried_object_id() )` can also work

[WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors)

Comment: Got it! Thank you. Is there a way of checking if the page has an ancestor and only output the parent title and id if it has an ancestor?

Comment: @benH The array is empty if it doesn't have ancestors.

Comment: `get_queried_object_id()` is safer than using `$post`, which can be overwritten with a secondary query.

Comment: If i use this to get the title it shows the ancestor title on the child page, great! however it shows the current title on the ancestor page: `get_page(array_pop(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)))->post_title;`

Comment: Also, I am using this to get the ID. The parent id shows on the child page and nothing shows on the parent page which is how the title should be: `array_pop(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));`